# Google Analytics: Filter by Custom Dimension Value

Tags: google-analytics

I'm working with Google's custom dimensions; and currently have things setup like this:

`gtag('config', 'UA-12345-1', { listing: '1234'});`

Barring me setting that up incorrectly  how would I go about filtering the dashboard down to that specific listing and listing value?

I'm looking for a dashboard view and then (if you happen to know) if there's any differences for how I'd grab that data via the API as well to show within a dashboard. Thanks!

Comment: You would need to either create a segment to target that specific listing or create custom reports where you pull the CD data and then do a filter on the report based on the listing that you want. Pulling this CD through the API would be no different than pulling any other dimension.

Comment: Hey @XTOTHEL thanks for the response. Does the parameters themselves look correct up there? I'm having trouble even finding that `listing` custom dimension, so I wanted to make sure I was writing the syntax correctly.

Comment: Have you created the custom dimension in GA?https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en Have you done a custom_map so that you can call it "listing"? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets

Comment: Think I was able to figure it out with those links. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check above comments for documentation.